# kubernetes service and endpoints with 2 ports

Tags: kubernetes

I have postgres instance running outside kubernetes cluster on port 5434.
Service manifest looks like below. Everything works well.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 5432
    targetPort: 5434
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: postgres
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 10.1.0.210
    ports:
      - port: 5434
```

But when I want add one additional port (5434) on my service it stops working (both ports). Manifest:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 5432
    targetPort: 5434
    name: p1
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 5434
    targetPort: 5434
    name: p2
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: postgres
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 10.1.0.210
    ports:
      - port: 5434
```

Comment: are you creating endpoints manually ?

Comment: For some services Yes.